# `APP_INITIALIZER` - by User choice, Is it possible?

Tags: angular, azure, angular7, adal

I am implemented `azure` and `adal.js` with my application. this application used by 2 group of people. so I am keeping 2 separate configuration. the `MsAdalAngular6Module` takes the configuration on app initiation itself.

But I require, let the app stop the initiation until the login option available in screen, so the user let select their group, then service can supply the config what they required for app initialization.

Is it possible with Angular? or what is the correct approach to initialize the app with different configurations by user choice?

I tried with provider but getting error, `Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[InjectionToken` 
I added both service and login component in `deps:[]` array. how to come up with solution here?

Any one advice me please?

here is my try:

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeApp,
      multi: true,
      deps: [AppConfig, SignInComponent] //added both service and component throw error..
    },
    MsAdalAngular6Service,
    {
      provide: 'adalConfig',
      useFactory: getAdalConfig,
      deps: []
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: InsertAuthTokenInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this work, I created a custom service and implemented. it works fine for me.

here is my service file.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';
import { StateShared } from "./../models/models";
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppConfig  {

    value:boolean = true;
    option:string;
    popup = `
    <div class="site-wrapper"
        style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;
        min-height:100vh;border:0.5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0)">
    <div Id="optionHolder" class="main-section" style="
        flex: 1;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction:row;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        padding:0 15px;
    ">

        <div class="singin-options" style="
            border: 3px dotted gray;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction:column;
            padding:1rem;

        ">
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline" style="
             margin-bottom: 1rem;
            ">
                <input class="form-check-input" (change)="onLoginChange($event)" value="CTS" type="radio" name="loginOption" id="inlineRadio1">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">Login as CTS Member</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" (change)="onLoginChange($event)" value="IBO" type="radio" name="loginOption" id="inlineRadio2">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Login as IBO Member</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="signin" style="padding:1rem;">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Sign In</button>
        </div>

    </div></div>`

    constructor(private store:Store<StateShared>){}

    userOption:any;

    setUserOption() {

        let that = this;

        if(!this.value) return;

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            if(!localStorage.getItem("name")){

                $('body').append(this.popup);

                $("input[name=loginOption]:radio").change(function (event) {
                    that.userOption =  $(event.target).val();
                    $("button").prop('disabled', false);
                })

                $("button").prop('disabled', true);

                $("button").click(function () {
                    that.value = false;
                    localStorage.setItem("name", that.userOption);
                    resolve(true);

                })
            }

            if(localStorage.getItem("name")){
                resolve(true);
            }



        });
    }

    getUserOption(){

        $('body #optionWrapper').remove();

        switch (localStorage.getItem("name")) {
            case "CTS":
                return {
                    tenant: 'de08c407-19b9-427d-9fe8-edf254300ca7',
                    clientId: '828002a4-149f-478c-a318-933ad52b4c4f',
                    redirectUri: window.location.origin,
                    endpoints: {
                        "https://iboconfigservice.azurewebsites.net/api/":"828002a4-149f-478c-a318-933ad52b4c4f"
                    },
                    navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
                    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
                    expireOffsetSeconds: 600,
                    postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin
                };

            case "IBO":
                return {
                    tenant: 'intbacdev.onmicrosoft.com',
                    clientId: '5a5e1a7e-b31d-47bc-9be4-5a107f67fedb',
                    redirectUri: window.location.origin,
                    endpoints: {
                        "https://iboconfigservice.azurewebsites.net/api/":"828002a4-149f-478c-a318-933ad52b4c4f"
                    },
                    navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
                    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
                    expireOffsetSeconds: 600,
                    postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin
                };


            default:
                // code...
                break;
        }



    }

}
```